# Gnuplot: Multiple "for" loops cause plots to multiply

Tags: loops, gnuplot

I'm attempting to plot multiple XRD patterns on one graph, with a vertical offset between them. Files are named E65.xy for example

Currently, This works:

```
reset 
set xlabel "2 Theta"
set ylabel "Intensity"
set xrange [5:60]
set key outside right
set border 3
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set terminal pdf color font 'times new roman,17'
set output "XRD_E65.pdf"
offset = 400
plot 'E58.xy' using 1:($2 + offset*5)   with lines ls 1 lc 1 title "E58 XRD"    , \
    'E59.xy' using 1:($2 + offset*4)    with lines ls 1 lc 2 title "E59 XRD"    , \
    'E61.xy' using 1:($2 + offset*3)    with lines ls 1 lc 3 title "E61 XRD"    , \
    'E62.xy' using 1:($2 + offset*2)    with lines ls 1 lc 4 title "E62 XRD"    , \
    'E64.xy' using 1:($2 + offset*1)    with lines ls 1 lc 5 title "E64 XRD"    , \
    'E65.xy' using 1:($2 + offset*0)    with lines ls 1 lc 6 title "E65 XRD"
```

I have quite a few to plot, so I'm trying to use loops. I've managed to get this far:

```
offset = 400
explist = "58 59 61 62 64 65"
plot for [exp in explist] "E".exp.".xy" using 1:($2 + offset * (count) ) with lines title "E".exp
```

Which plots all six patterns on top of each other. I've been wanting to try to add `for [count=1:6]` after the first `for` argument" but when I do that, I get 36 plots, (six sets of plots offset by 400).

I think I understand why this has happened, but I  can't find a solution to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the `for [count=1:6]` you’re actually creating a nested loop, thus plotting all possible combinations of offset and exp values.

You should consider the following alternative:

```
offsetlist = "5 4 3 2 1 0"
explist = "58 59 61 62 64 65"
plot for [i=1:6] "E".word(explist, i).".xy" using 1:($2 + word(offsetlist, i)) w l title "E".word(explist, i)
```

Comment: Thanks, with the addition of `offset*` prior to `word(offsetlist, i)` that works. Without that multiplier, It's hard to see the offset, as the peaks are quite high

Comment: That’s right, I didn’t pay attention to the offset multiplier!